# Suspend forked process at startup

Tags: c, pthreads, posix, solaris

I want to suspend (pause) a forked process at startup and resume it later on. Is there any way to do that with POSIX or Solaris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by using a semaphore and a signal handler. To wake up the child, the parent process sends a signal to the child process which in turn posts the semaphore from within the signal handler. The child, which was waiting on that semaphore, then wakes up.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just call `pause()` in code of child process after fork?

Comment: Either that, or a call to sigsuspend(2), followed by a kill(pid, SIGXXX) from parent, where SIGXXX is the signal of choice. SIGCONT maybe?

Comment: @Jorgen, sigsuspend doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @Jorgen, sigsuspend blocks the delivery of signals... it sounds like you were implying it would actually suspend the process. Perhaps I misunderstood what you were going for.

Comment: Look at the man page again. It's a generalied version of pause(2).

Answer (score -1):

You could send your process `SIGSTOP`, then resume with `SIGCONT`.

Comment: Is it safe to send SIGSTOP in the middle of execution? Isn't their a way to suspend it from the very beginning? Ptrace is one thing that comes in my mind.

Comment: You just recommended a solution that is susceptible to race conditions.

Comment: You can always use raise to send a signal: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/raise.html